# Como fechar janela VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Toda vez que estou codando no VSCode, ela fica aparecendo pequenas janelas de sugestões a todo momento. E não é aquela mesma do atalho "Ctrl + Espaço". Essa que estou falando é uma outra janela.
Vocês sabem como posso desabilitar isso? Pois ela entra na frente do código e atrapalha a visualização

[image: O a janela é essa em vermelho]

A janela é essa em vermelho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é do Intellisense vc pode ver mais opções aqui https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense

Mas basicamente esse código vai fazer as sugestões desaparecerem enquanto vc digita, vc tem que salvar esse código no `JSON` dos `Settings` ok

```
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  }
```

Comment: Precisei adicionar "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false, esse código também, aí funcionou. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Coloquei na primeira linha do `settings.json`

```
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
```

e resolveu. Nenhuma dica é mostrada ao hover.